# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

Two components are rendered with conditional rendering with a redux state but after changing redux state from one component warning appears that can't perform state update on unmounted component. In LoginWrapper.js Login and Redirect are two components with conditional rendering using isLoggedIn state of redux.

LoginWrapper.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import Login from 'containers/Login';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

const LoginWrapper = ({ isLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        !isLoggedIn
        ?
        <Login />
        :
        <Redirect to="/profile" />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

LoginWrapper.defaultProps = {
  isLoggedIn: false
}

LoginWrapper.propTypes = {
  isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginWrapper);
```

Login.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withFormik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logInUser } from 'actions/auth';
import { logInUrl } from "apis";
import ModalLayout from "shared/ModalLayout";
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const loginPost = (history, values, setSubmitting, setErrors, resetForm, logIn) => {
  const { username, password } = values;

  window.fetch(logInUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "username": username,
        "password": password
      })
    })
    .then((results) => {
        return results.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if(data.errors) {
        setErrors({ 'username': data.errors[0].msg });
      } else {
        logIn(data.user, history);
        resetForm();
      }
      setSubmitting(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
}

const LogInForm = ({
    touched,
    errors,
    isSubmitting,
  }) => (
      <ModalLayout>
        <Form className="login-form">
          {touched.username && errors.username && <p className="login-error">{errors.username}</p>}
          <div className="login-username">
            <Field type="input" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
          </div>
          {touched.password && errors.password && <p className="login-error">{errors.password}</p>}
          <div className="login-password">
            <Field type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
          </div>
          <div className="login-button">
            <button className="modal-button login-button" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              Log in
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="login-redirect">
            <Link to="/signup">Don&apos;t have an account.Create one</Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </ModalLayout>
    );

LogInForm.propTypes = {
  isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  touched: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const FormikApp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues() {
    return {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    }
  },
  handleSubmit(values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting, props }) {
    const { logIn, history } = props;
    loginPost(history, values, setSubmitting, setErrors, resetForm, logIn);
  },
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().required('Username is required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  })
})(LogInForm);

export default withRouter(connect(null, { logIn: logInUser })(FormikApp));
```

actions

```js
import {
  LOG_IN,
  LOG_OUT,
} from 'actions/types';

import { logInUrl } from 'apis';

export const logInUser = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOG_IN,
      payload: user
    })
  }
}

export const logOutUser = () => {
  return {
    type: LOG_OUT
  }
}
```

reducers

```js
import { LOG_IN, LOG_OUT } from 'actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isloggedIn: null,
  user: null,
  uid: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOG_IN:
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: true, user: action.payload, uid: action.payload.id }
    case LOG_OUT:
      return { ...state, isLoggedIn: false, user: null, uid: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation of Login component and your reducers too?

Comment: Yes, please check it now

Comment: try making your `Login` component a route instead of mounting a component in the conditional statement, redirect it to `/login` route

Comment: its not working like that. What is actually want is redirect to profile route after succefully fetching user data after submitting form in login.js and allow login route only if user is not logged in and allow profile route if user is logged in, so i used the isLoggedIn state in redux